# Reporting someones suggestion

Tags: word-choice, reported-speech, idiomatic-language

Suppose someone said:

> "Why don't we go camping this year?"

Would it be correct to say:

> She suggested that we could go camping that summer.

I can't say:

> She suggested going camping that summer.

My answer was brought about by unacceptable using of two Gerunds whereas saying "going for a camping" isn't idiomatic according to the research done by me some minutes ago. I am right, aren't I? Or there exist some alternative ways of solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Why don't we go camping this year?**"

Would it be correct to say:

**She suggested that we could go camping that summer**. ?

Answer: Yes, that is correct.

**She suggested going camping that summer**.

Answer: Yes, that is also correct.

**Go camping** is idiomatic, like **go sailing** or **go hunting** or **go dancing** to name a few and it's fine to have two ing endings: going camping. In fact, to make it a noun it has to be: going camping.

**Going camping is fun, isn't it?**

That is completely idiomatic. Going camping is the phrasal subject there.

Going camping is not two gerunds. Go camping is a verb and a noun, a set phrase (the activity of camping is a noun taken from a gerund, that is very common in English). Going camping functions as subject or direct object and is considered a single thing, made up of one verb and one noun.

Comment: Take my apologies for not having read you reply to my post before. As it turned out, I didn't consider it as set phrase made up of a verb and a noun. You did me a favour by writing such an expanded answer. Thank you very much.